# SSRS 2005 matrix not showing the data

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, grouping

My query returns the following results( with soem sample data):

```
STUID   FirstName  LastName DeptID  CourseRequested
1       xxxx       yyyy     2353    Algebra
1       xxxx       yyyy     2353    Trignometry
1       xxxx       yyyy     2356    Biology
1       xxxx       yyyy     2356    Chesmistry
```

This woule like this for all students. So, a student can request multiple courses in one department.

Now, I want my report to look like this :

```
                     2353           2356
1 xxxx yyyyy         algebra        Biology
1 xxxx yyyy          Trignometry    Chemistry
```

So, I used a matrix with row group on StuID, Fname and LName. Column Group on DepartmentID and CourseName on Detail.

But, the result set shows me only the first row with 'Algebra and Biology'. It is not repeating the second set of courses. I need not repeat the StuID,Fname and Lname for the second row.

I dont know what am I doing worng. Pleas help me. Let me know if there is another approach rather than using the matrix.
So, I have to go with sub reports or Table?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing output is grouped by StuID, Fname, LName and DepartmentID.

For each combination of these (in the sample data), you have more than one CourseRequested. So the report returns the first value for each group combination.

To format your crosstab as desired, you need to add another row grouping condition, to split the different CourseRequested values on to separate rows. I suggest doing this by row number or rank in your sql query - assuming you are using SQLServer for your data source, add the following column to your select statement:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by StuID, Fname, LName, DepartmentID 
                   order by CourseRequested) as RN
```

- then add RN to your row grouping conditions in the crosstab, and the output should be formatted as required.