# SSRS 2008 How to group row data under column headings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I know this is easy, but not if you don't know how. I'm trying to create a report in SSRS 2008 (not R2).

I have the following data returned in my query:

```
dept                quadrant        inv_quadrant    title    

Analgesics          High/High   High/High   Existing
Cough & Cold        High/High   High/High   Existing
Dispensary          High/High   High/High   Existing
First Aid & Wound   High/Low    Low/Low     Movement
Confectionary       Low/High    Low/High    Existing
Family Planning     Low/High    Low/High    Existing
Foot Care           Low/High    Low/Low     Movement
Medicines S2 & S3   Low/High    Low/High    Existing
Oral Hygiene        Low/High    Low/High    Existing
Stomach & Bowel     Low/High    Low/Low     Movement
Baby                Low/Low     Low/Low     Existing
First Aid & Wound   Low/Low     High/Low    New
Foot Care           Low/Low     Low/High    New
```

I would like the data to be grouped by quadrant and then by title within the quadrant, like so:

```
High/High    Existing             Movement            New
             Analgesics
             Cough & Cold
             Dispensary
High/Low                          First Aid & Wound
Low/High     Confectionary        Foot Care
             Family Planning      Stomach & Bowel
             Medicines S2 & S3
             Oral Hygiene
Low/Low      Baby                                     First Aid & Wound
                                                      Foot Care
```

I can almost get it to present like this by creating a table with row group on quadrant, but then the data in the columns is presented line-by-line instead of directly below its column heading, like this:

```
High/High    Existing             Movement            New
             Analgesics
             Cough & Cold
             Dispensary
High/Low                          First Aid & Wound
Low/High     Confectionary        
             Family Planning      
                                  Foot Care
             Medicines S2 & S3
             Oral Hygiene
                                  Stomach & Bowel

Low/Low      Baby
                                                      First Aid & Wound
                                                      Foot Care
```

I also tried using a matrix with row group on quadrant and column group on title but it's only showing one record per quadrant(??)...

I'm sure I need some kind of column grouping or something basic to fix this. Also the query is a fairly complex union of 4 temp tables (nasty, I didn't write it) so if I can avoid using a dense_rank as I've seen mentioned in similar cases, I'd prefer to and not mess with the query unless there's no other way.

Thank you so much!

Comment: according to you your requirement is to "I would like the data to be grouped by quadrant and then by title within the quadrant, like so:" if you look closer at your desired output , your 1st Column has `quadrant` values and after that it all messed up , your second Column has values from `Dept` and also from `Title` and thrid and fourth column also has values from all over the place. Even though you are reporting but you need to show `One type of Data in One and Only One Column` . I think you need to look at your report design again.

Comment: The requirement you have stated its pretty simple just Add a Tablix --> Add `Title`  --> Add a Parent Group --> Drag n Drop `Dept` from Dataset --> Add Another Parent Group --> Drag n Drop `quadrant` into that parent group and your good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured this would happen. It turns out I *did* need to modify the query to include a DENSE_RANK...

I added DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY quadrant, title ORDER BY jrdept_name) AS RNK then added RNK to the already existant Quadrant row grouping and that did the trick...

And this was added to the matrix version of my original solution so it already had Title as a column grouping as well.

Giving credit where credit is due I got the answer from here: [SSRS 2005 matrix not showing the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519974/ssrs-2005-matrix-not-showing-the-data)

Thanks!